# How to let a auto layout constraint depend on sibling view?

Tags: swift

I am trying to overlay an canvas view on top of a `UIImageView` to draw some customized lines.

I am trying to let the canvas autolayout constraint depend on the `UIImageView`. But It is not working: when I debug in xcode layout debugger, the frame of `UIImageView` is a rectangle of size 400 x 700, but the Canvas view frame size is 0x0.

The code is relatively simple:

```
class Canvas : UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }



        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x:100  , y: 100)

        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(7)

        context.move(to: startPoint)
        context.addLine(to: endPoint)

        context.strokePath()
    }


}

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    let canvas:Canvas = {
        let canvas = Canvas()
        canvas.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        canvas.alpha = 0.2
        return canvas
    } ()

    let photoView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()

        imageView.image =     UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "hongjinbao")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return imageView
    } ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // stack views
        view.addSubview(photoView)
        view.addSubview(canvas)

        setupLayout()


    }

    private func setupLayout() {





        photoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        photoView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        photoView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

        photoView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        canvas.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        canvas.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        canvas.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

        canvas.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true




        // this two works together
//        photoView.frame = view.frame
//        canvas.frame = photoView.frame
    }


}
```

Did I missed something? If I set the size using `.frame` it works (see the comments near the end). But I want to use the Autolayout anchors to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set

```
canvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```